# How to implement textSwitcher with inimation inside Ontick

Tags: android, text, textview, countdowntimer, switchers

I am creating a code to show animation of text (sliding from top to bottom) and that text is changing every second, I am using a CountDownTimer and a textSwitcher.
Please refer to the code below.

the code compiles normally, however it crashes the app once I try to access the activity containing the textswitcher.

```
 final TextSwitcher sec_sw = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
    sec_sw.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
    sec_sw.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_top);

    new CountDownTimer(differenceleft, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            days_tv.setText(""+String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished)));
            hours_tv.setText(""+String.format("%02d",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)- TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished))));
            min_tv.setText("" + String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished))));
            //sec_tv.setText("" + String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            sec_sw.setText("" + String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            /*_tv.setText("done!");*/
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message? It will help a lot–to answerers and yourself.

Comment: the error ,message says: Unfortunately, AppName has stopped.